# Are there any guidelines for vertical layout and spacing?

Tags: website-design, layout, grid

The proliferation of grid systems have made it easy to determine the horizontal layout of a site - column widths and margins are just made to fit into the correct grid spacing.

But what about vertical layout?

Are there any guidelines to determine the relationships between font-sizes, vertical margins, image heights and other vertical alignments?

Comment: \not really a guideline, but there's the Google Labs Browsersize page that'll tell you the average sizes people have browser window set to: http://browsersize.googlelabs.com/

Comment: Should be migrated to graphic design

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Vertical rhythm: HTML practice / info](http://24ways.org/2006/compose-to-a-vertical-rhythm)

[The ultimate resource
in grid systems / website](http://www.thegridsystem.org/)

[CSS Vertical rhythm calculator / tool](http://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm)

[Typograph : Scale & rhythm / tool](http://lamb.cc/typograph/)